# Matching 2 datas in Lists and acquired numbers

Tags: python, list

How can I extract numbers with matching results of lists A and B:

Here is my code:

```py
A = ['D(1)', ' A(2)', 'C(3)', 'B(4)', 'E(5)']
B = ['A','B','C','D','E']
```

Expected List:

```
C = [2,4,3,1,5]
```

Please help. Many thanks in advance.

Results:

```
C : [2,4,3,1,5]
```

Comment: As with any programming problem, you can break this problem down into smaller tasks. You have probably identified that the elements in your `A` list contain the _key_ by which you want to look up an integer, and its corresponding value surrounded in parentheses. The `B` list contains the keys for which you want the values in your output `C`. Can you think of a data structure that organizes data as key-value pairs?

Comment: One step you will need to do is to separate the "keys" and "values" in the elements of `A`. The next step will be to look up the values for the keys specified in `B`, and collecting them in a list. If you've identified these steps and made an attempt, please specify which of these steps are you having trouble with. If you have not yet made an attempt, please do so and ask a _specific_ question once you have enough information to know where you are actually stuck.

Comment: Please also read  [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953), 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188), and 
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Pasting your homework prompt here without including your own analysis is not okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` module to parse the string for letters/numbers or `str.split`:

```py
A = ["D(1)", "A(2)", "C(3)", "B(4)", "E(5)"]
B = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

m = {v.split("(")[0]: int(v.split("(")[1][:-1]) for v in A}

out = [m[v] for v in B]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```